# Wicket create images from file system

Tags: java, image, wicket

I am making a project in which user when click on a product a modal window open with the product name. I also want to include the product image on my modal window inside a panel. Images are stored on my server in a directory.

I am referring to this link

My panel html code look like this http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/

ItemOrderPanel.html

```
        <div>
            <li><a wicket:id="link"></a></li>
        </div>
```

ItemOrderPanel.java

```
    final ResourceReference imageResourceReference = new ImageResourceReference();
    String imageName = itm.getProductImage();
    final PageParameters parameters = new PageParameters();
    parameters.set("name", imageName);
    CharSequence urlForImage = getRequestCycle().urlFor(imageResourceReference,parameters);
    ExternalLink link = new ExternalLink("link", urlForImage.toString());
    link.setBody(Model.of(imageName));
    add(link);
```

In WicketApplication.java

```
mountResource("/orderPage/{name}",new ImageResourceReference());
```

I have doubt about this line in WicketApplication.java.

I have created resource file like this

ImageResourceReference.java

```
public class ImageResourceReference extends ResourceReference{

public ImageResourceReference(){
    super(ImageResourceReference.class,"imagesDemo");
}

@Override
public IResource getResource() {
    return new ImageResource();
}

private static class ImageResource extends DynamicImageResource{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected byte[] getImageData(Attributes attributes) {
        PageParameters parameters = attributes.getParameters();
        StringValue name = parameters.get("name");

                    byte[] imageBytes = null;
        if(name.isEmpty() == false)
            imageBytes = getImageAsBytes(name.toString());

        return imageBytes;
    }

    private byte[] getImageAsBytes(String label){
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        //g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 48));
        g.drawString(label, 50, 50);
        g.dispose();

        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
        ImageWriter writer = writers.next();
        if (writer == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("JPG not supported?!");
        }

        final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] imageBytes = null;
        try {

            ImageOutputStream imageOut = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
            writer.setOutput(imageOut);
            writer.write(image);
            imageOut.close();
            imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageBytes;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that){
        return that instanceof ImageResource;
    }

}
```

}

But when i debug the code I found out that control is not coming to internal **ImageResource class** which is returning bytes.

I want to display the image picture on my panel. And the link that is showing on my panel is the link what i stored in my database which is of the local system.

Any help and advice appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i settled on this code in ItemOrderPanel.java

```
add(new NonCachingImage("img", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<DynamicImageResource>(){
          @Override public DynamicImageResource getObject() {
            DynamicImageResource dir = new DynamicImageResource() {
              @Override protected byte[] getImageData(Attributes attributes) {
                  StringValue name = parameters.get("name");
                  byte[] imageBytes = null;
                    if(name.isEmpty() == false)
                        imageBytes = getImageAsBytes(name.toString());

                    return imageBytes;
              }
            };
            dir.setFormat("image/png");
            return dir;
          }
        }));

private byte[] getImageAsBytes(String label){
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream inStream  = new FileInputStream(new File(label));
            copy(inStream, outStream);
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
            return outStream.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } 
     return imageBytes;


}

private void copy(InputStream source, OutputStream destination)
        throws IOException
    {

        // Transfer bytes from source to destination
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = source.read(buf)) > 0) {
                destination.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            source.close();
            destination.close();

    }
```

Comment: I know this is a nit-pick and I'm incredibly sorry, but you don't need the try/catch in your copy method since it throws the `IOException` anyway. Nice answer though, definitely helped me out!

Comment: Yes you are write. Thanks buddy

Comment: @CodeFish But where do you put the path? I dont see that.. Did you did without the ImageResourceReference as shown in your question above? just the "add(.." statement in your Panel or what? Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use DynamicImageResource and get image in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you create two different instances of ImageResourceReference (and I think this is a problem in the original article as well). So I would do the following in your ItemOrderPanel.java:

```
WebApplication.get().
        getResourceReferenceRegistry().
        getResourceReference(
            ImageResourceReference.class,
            "imagesDemo",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            true,
            false)
```

Also make sure that you didn't map any other resources or pages with an URL which is very general, like "/" which could have higher priority than "orderPage". According to the Wiki page below:

> *Mappers with bigger IRequestMapper.getCompatibilityScore(Request) are asked first.*

Look at this page for the details:
[How request mapping works in Wicket](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/request-mapping.html)

It should work fine then! ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/uploaddownload.html

you can find some information here.

Comment: Yes but it is not working in my case because I am using Wicket 1.5 and WebResource is not available in Wicket 1.5

Comment: The site is unreachable :(