# How to get images to display it in Wicket?

Tags: java, user-interface, wicket

I am stuck with images. I need to upload an image and then display it on my page.
What I am doing now is uploading file like this:

```
private Picture picture;       *// picture model*
private FileUploadField fileUpload;

public PictureUploader() {


    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("uploadForm") {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -694488846250739923L;

        protected void onSubmit() {

            FileUpload uploadedFile = fileUpload.getFileUpload();
            File newFile = new File(uploadedFile.getClientFileName());
            picture.setImage(newFile);

            PageParameters pageParameter = new PageParameters();
            pageParameter.put("file", picture.getImage());

            setResponsePage(DataPage.class,pageParameter);
        }

    };

    add(form);
    form.setMultiPart(true);
    form.add(setFileUpload(new FileUploadField("fileUpload")));
}
```

Then I submit it and go to DataPage ( I show only the constructor):

```
public DataPage(final PageParameters parameters) {

        File file;
        if (parameters.containsKey("file")) {
                // WHAT TO DO HERE? SINCE GET() FROM PAGEPARAMETERS DOES NOT WORK FOR IT!
        }

        final Label result = new Label("result", ?????);
        add(result);

    }
```

Who knows how to make it, please, help me figure it out.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971043/wicket-create-images-from-file-system?rq=1) from @user3241004 in a deleted link only answer

Comment: Did I catch you want to display an uploaded image in your page as an <image src="some_dynamic_image_path"> tag and you don't know how to create the dynamic image path required in the src attribute of the html element? (add the Wicket version you're using)

Comment: I am learning wicket. it will be displayed from database, but now I am just testing how can I do it without database. Later, if i want to display image from database, Should I need convert bytes back to image file? P.s. I do not know how to pass uploaded image in DataPage through PageParameters.

Comment: Storing and displaying images from database has been already discussed on StackOverflow few times. Between two pages, you can make a contract using any object you want, just the new page has to have a construtor with object type you require to be a subject of contract, for example then you invoke that page setResponsePage(new DataPage(uploadedFile));